# A continuous-time signal is given as () = ^(0.1*t)e^((/2)t) [( − 2) − ( − 10)]

Tags: complex-numbers

A continuous-time signal is given as () = ^(0.1*t)e^((/2)t) [( − 2) − ( − 10)]

How can I find the Re[x(t)], Im[x(t)], |[x(t)]| and the phase of x(t)? Also, I need to sketch them and show important values.

My answer is Re[x(t)] = ^(0.1*t)cos(/2)t = 0 ,
Im[x(t)] = ^(0.1*t)sin(/2)t = ^(0.1*t)t, |[x(t)]| = ^(0.1*t) and phase =  (/2)t

I don't know if they are all correct and how to sketch them

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations.